# QDesktopServices::openUrl does not work, neither for URLs nor for local files, on two platforms

Tags: qt

I have a code as simple as this:

```
int main() {

   QUrl url("http://google.com");
   if (!QDesktopServices::openUrl(url)  )
       qDebug() << "Failed to open url";

   return 0;   
}
```

Running the code gives "Failed to open url". Tried on Ubuntu with Qt 5.5.1 and on MS Windows with Qt 5.7. No difference.

Local files also do not open:

```
int main() {

   QString file = "/home/user/testfile.pdf";
   if (!QDesktopServices::openUrl( QUrl::fromLocalFile(file)  ) )
       qDebug() << "Failed to open file";

   return 0;   
}
```

Again, "Failed to open file". On both Ubuntu and Windows. I can see some discussion in stackoverflow about openUrl, but they are concerned with specific features, such as failing to open urls with spaces, etc. But here it just doesn't work at all, on two independent platforms. What do I miss?

Comment: is there is any specific configuration of default webbrowser on your machine? Examples seems to be fine.

Comment: On Ubuntu the default browser is Firefox, on Windows it is Chrome. I didn't make any specific configurations.

Comment: What I've found just now is that if I use the same QDesktopServices::openUrl not as a standalone code but within the context of a bigger GUI application I'm developing - it works! (both on Ubuntu and Windows). It seems as if some additional stuff is needed for openUrl to work, but why then doesn't it produce any dependency errors at compiling the example above?

Comment: Try initializing QApplication in your code, it **may** have something to do with the event system.

Comment: It's not about the event system; rather, `QApplication` loads libraries to make things like `QDesktopServices` work when it is constructed. Without a `QApplication` instance, no desktop services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[QDesktopServices](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopservices.html) is part of the [Qt GUI](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtgui-index.html) module. Therefore, in order to use any function related to `QDesktopServices`, you will need to instantiate at least a [QGuiApplication](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html) :

> Since the QGuiApplication object does so much initialization, it must
>   be created before any other objects related to the user interface are
>   created.

In fact, you can create a [QApplication](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html) (as @Alex Spataru suggested), since it inherits `QGuiApplication`. To make your code work, you just need this :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

   QApplication app(argc, argv); // just this line

   QUrl url("http://google.com");
   if ( !QDesktopServices::openUrl(url) )
       qDebug() << "Failed to open url";

   return 0;   
}
```